# delphi TColor format Negative

Tags: delphi, tcolor

hopefully an easy question, but I could not find an answer. I am using Delphi TColor and some color values are negative. Is this documented? I need to do some color conversions, for example, to RGB.

for example: Label.Color=-16777188; //light bluish

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The negative values are not actual RGB colours, but Windows system colours, which are variable.

For instance, the following are actual RGB colours:

```
clRed   = $000000FF; {00BBGGRR}
clBlue  = $00FF0000;
clWhite = $00FFFFFF;
clBlack = $00000000;
```

Here are some system colours:

```
clWindow        = $FF000005;
clWindowText    = $FF000008;
clHighlight     = $FF00000D;
clActiveCaption = $FF000002;
```

These are not actual RGB values, but represent your system colours. Often, `clWindow` is white, `clWindowText` is black, `clHighlight` is some kind of blue etc., but -- again -- these settings can be changed in Windows.

When these 32-bit integers are interpreted as *signed* 32-bit integers, they become negative. That's what you are seeing:

```
clWindow        = -16777211;
clWindowText    = -16777208;
clHighlight     = -16777203;
clActiveCaption = -16777214;
```

So in your case, -16777188 is not guaranteed to be "light bluish". In hex, this value is `$FF00001C` and I recognize this as `clGradientInactiveCaption`, that is, the second gradient colour of an inactive unthemed (Windows 9x-styled) window titlebar.

As you know, in the VCL you can use these system colours as if they were actual colours. But -- of course -- the actual colours you get might vary from user to user.

You can obtain an actual RGB colour from such a system colour by using the `ColorToRGB` function. On my system, `ColorToRGB(clGradientInactiveCaption)` yields `$00F2E4D7` (indeed light bluish).

Comment: To add to this, when you want to specify a specific RGB value and not a system color, you should use the `Windows.RGB()` function, don't use numeric values directly

Comment: As they said (I want to remark), keep in mind that every user might have a different colour when using System Colours, which probably is a behaviour you want to avoid.

Answer (score 4):

Delphi defines the Windows system colors like

```
SysGradientInactiveCaption = TColor(SystemColor or cGRADIENTINACTIVECAPTION);
```

With

```
SystemColor = $FF000000;
```

and

```
cGRADIENTINACTIVECAPTION = 28;
```

this ends up as -16777188.

These constants can be found in *System.UITypes.pas* under `TColorRec`.

Comment: Thank you Andreas and Uwe for answering the question  ;)