# Why does two differents TColor values corresponds to the same displayed color?

Tags: delphi, colors, vcl

I noticed that `clWhite` (`16777215`) and `clBtnHighlight` (`-16777196`) values ​​(`Vcl.Graphics.TColor`) are both displayed as white (At least on my machine).

I've tested it converting to Hex and both displays `FFFFFF`

```
ShowMessage(
  IntToHex(GetRValue(ColorToRGB(clWhite)), 2) +
  IntToHex(GetGValue(ColorToRGB(clWhite)), 2) +
  IntToHex(GetBValue(ColorToRGB(clWhite)), 2) + sLineBreak +
  IntToHex(GetRValue(ColorToRGB(clBtnHighlight)), 2) +
  IntToHex(GetGValue(ColorToRGB(clBtnHighlight)), 2) +
  IntToHex(GetBValue(ColorToRGB(clBtnHighlight)), 2)
);
```

I've found this definition which makes me think it is a "special" color value:

> clBtnHighlight    Represents the color of the highlighting on a button.

Is `clBtnHighlight` always interpreted as `clWhite` or does it depend on the OS or something else?

Comment: This is essentially a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62263083/delphi-tcolor-format-negative. In summary: Yes, negative `TColor` values represent the current Windows settings.

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: Yes, it answers my question, thank you

Comment: Why not simply searching in [the manual](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Colors_in_the_VCL)?