# How to get RGB values for a system color?

Tags: delphi, colors, delphi-xe7, systemcolors

I've always used `GetRValue`, `GetGValue` and `GetBValue` functions (From `Winapi.Windows` unit) for extracting the RGB values for a `TColor`.

Unfortunately, the same approach does not seem to be good for [system colors](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Sydney/en/Colors_in_the_VCL) like `clWindow`, `clBtnFace` and so on.

**For example:**

```
var
  MyColor : TColor;
begin
  MyColor := clBtnFace;

  ShowMessage(
    'R = ' + IntToStr(GetRValue(MyColor)) + sLineBreak +
    'G = ' + IntToStr(GetGValue(MyColor)) + sLineBreak +
    'B = ' + IntToStr(GetBValue(MyColor))
  );
end;
```

It produces the following output:

> R = 15
>
> G = 0
>
> B = 0

Which should looks like this:

[image: Picture of color RGB(15,0,0)]

On my system, I see the following color instead:

[image: Picture of color clBtnFace rendered on my system]

Comment: http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.ColorToRGB

Comment: You knew this [a month ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64888683/why-does-two-differents-tcolor-values-corresponds-to-the-same-displayed-color)! :)

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand: It seems you're right, what a wise man I was a month ago! :D.... (I've probably copied that from somewhere without knowing that `ColorToRGB` was "resolving" the system colors, my fault!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using `Get(R|G|B)Value()` will work just fine with system colors, you just need to convert them to RGB first. Use the [`ColorToRGB()`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Sydney/en/Vcl.Graphics.ColorToRGB) function for that:

> Converts a TColor value into an RGB representation of the color.

For example:

```pascal
var
  MyColor: TColor;
  RGB: Longint;
begin
  MyColor := ...; // any valid TColor value, whether RGB or system constant...
  RGB := ColorToRGB(MyColor);

  ShowMessage(
    'R = ' + IntToStr(GetRValue(RGB)) + sLineBreak +
    'G = ' + IntToStr(GetGValue(RGB)) + sLineBreak +
    'B = ' + IntToStr(GetBValue(RGB))
  );
end;
```